# Rails 3 Add to Cart on Show Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following on my index file

```
<%= button_to '', line_items_path(:product_id => product), :remote => 'true', :class => 'addbasketbtn' %>
```

However I can not add this to the Show page it give me an error.

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: app/controllers/products_controller.rb:20:in `show'
In the log file that is the error

Comment: Can you please paste the error what you are getting from the log file so that we can know what the error is and where you are getting?

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `product' for #<#<Class:0x70acf33fbcc0>:0x70accc774b58>):
49:       <div id="product_basket_icon">
50:        <a href="#"><img src="/assets/Addproduct.png" /><a>
51:   <p class="product_basket_text"><a href="#">ADD TO QUOTE</p></a></a>
52:        <%= button_to '', line_items_path(:product_id => product), :remote => 'true', :class => 'addbasketbtn' %>
53:</div>
54:</div>
55:</div>
  app/views/products/show.html.erb:52:in_app_views_products_show_html_erb___1861116085_61943739133260'app/controllers/products_controller.rb:20:in `show'

Comment: I guess in your controller you have `@product = Product.find(params[:id])`... In your view just replace product with instance variable `@product` `<%= button_to '', line_items_path(:product_id => @product), :remote => 'true', :class => 'addbasketbtn' %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in your controller you have

```
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
```

In your view just replace product with instance variable @product

```
<%= button_to '', line_items_path(:product_id => @product), :remote => 'true', :class => 'addbasketbtn' %>
```